# How to pass the hostname to gen_tcp from the command line

Tags: tcp, elixir

I'd like to pass the hostname and port from the command line to gen_tcp.connect.

```
defmodule MyComm.Application do
  use Application

  def main(args \\ []) do
    {options, _, _} = parse_args(args)

    connect(options[:host], options[:port])
    # connect('localhost', options[:port])
  end

  def connect(host, port) do
    opts = [:binary, active: false]

    {:ok, socket} = :gen_tcp.connect(host, port, opts)

    :gen_tcp.send(socket, "123\r\n")
  end

  def parse_args(args \\ []) do
    OptionParser.parse(args, switches: [host: :string, port: :integer])
  end
end
```

Running the example above causes a :badarg error:

> ** (exit) :badarg
>       (kernel) gen_tcp.erl:149: :gen_tcp.connect/4
>       (mycomm) lib/application.ex:14: MyComm.Application.connect/2
>       (elixir) lib/kernel/cli.ex:76: anonymous fn/3 in Kernel.CLI.exec_fun/2

However, by hardcoding 'localhost' everything works fine.
What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to convert the string argument of host into a charlist. `:gen_tcp.connect/4` needs an erlang string (Elixir char list) for it's first argument.

Comment: Yes, that was it. Thanks.